# How to use infinite scroll in quasar to load more datas?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, infinite-scroll, quasar-framework, quasar

---

I am trying to load more data using quasar infinite scroll but i cannot load any more data infact it loads all the data once.... and i got

```
done() is not a function
```

Below is my method for infinite scroll

```
initDefaultData (done, index) {
  setTimeout (() => {
    if (this.datas) {
      db.collection('example').orderBy('created_at', 'desc').get().then(res => {
        if (res.size < 1) {
          this.noData = true
        } else {
          res.forEach((doc) => {
            this.datas.push({
              id: doc.id
            })
          })
        }
      })
      done()
    }
  }, 1000)
}
```

Here is where  i use infinite scroll in template

```
<q-infinite-scroll @load="initDefaultData">
  <q-card v-for="(data, index) in datas" :key="index" class="q-mb-md q-mt-sm">
  </q-card>
</q-infinite-scroll>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you mixed parameters order: `index` goes before `done`

```
initDefaultData (index, done) {
...
}
```